# Assign affinity for distributing the kubernetes pods across all nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

What rules should be used to assign affinity to Kubernetes pods for distributing the pods across all Availability Zones?
I have a region with 3 Availability Zones and Nodes in each of these. I want to make sure that each of the 3 pods are spread across all the 3 Availability Zones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the label `topology.kubernetes.io/zone` (for e.g. topologyKey) and add **anti-affinity** rules.

This is part of the [anti-affinity example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#an-example-of-a-pod-that-uses-pod-affinity):

```
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: security
              operator: In
              values:
              - S2
          topologyKey: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
```

the result of the example is documented as

> The pod anti-affinity rule says that the pod cannot be scheduled onto a node if that node is in the same zone as a pod with label having key "security" and value "S2".

Instead of the label `security` in the example, you can use e.g. `app-name: <your-app-name>` as label and use that in your `matchExpression`.